# Array + Curve Modifier not filling out fully

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, blender-osm

[image]

My curve is a bit odd - it is a gridlike structure (based on NYC streets). I want to place cars on the roads using the array and curve modifiers, but for some reason, when I do this, it only fills out a small portion. For a long straight line curve, it works perfectly, but for the grid-like curves, it doesn't (this is OpenStreetMap imported data, by the way).
Do you have any ideas on how I can fill out the entire grid with cars, just as the array and curve does on non-grid-like curves?
I want to be able to automate this process with code, so some manual splitting of the roads is not really an option

Comment: If the curve object contains disconnected curves you won't be able to use those curves for array modifiers. Edit the curves manually, making sure that there is only one continuos segment per curve object.